# Visual C# ListView ContextMenu

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView to display Images Icons, and i need 2 different Context menu on that ListView that have to show when i Right Click inside the ListView.

- ContextMenu1 have to show only when i Right Click on a Item
- ContextMenu2 have to show when i **DO NOT** Right click on a Item, but in the blank space of the ListView.

This is the current Code that i have, but it is only working when i right click on a item:

```
private void ListView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (ListView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y) is ListViewItem)
            {
                ContextMenu1.Show(Cursor.Position);
            }
            else
            {
                ContextMenu2.Show(Cursor.Position);
            }
        }
    }
```

What i did wrong?

Comment: so you want the ContextMenu2 to show up automatically when hovering over an item ?

Comment: @Omarrrio No. It have to show when i'm Right Clicking inside the ListView, but not over an item. *I have edited my question to be more clear what i want to do*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetItemAt will always return a ListviewItem. You should check for null like this example from MSDN:

```
private void ListView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (ListView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y) != null )
   {
          ContextMenu1.Show(Cursor.Position);

   }
       else
   {
          ContextMenu2.Show(Cursor.Position);
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working. Also using a Console.WriteLine(). The else statement is not firing.

Comment: The original example uses the MouseDown event.

Comment: @WiS3 This is the solution, i tried it, you just have to change yje ListView to your current listview and it should work like charm. Dont forget to put it on the MouseDown event

Answer (score 1):

Try using the MouseDown or MouseUp event instead:

```
listView1.MouseDown += listView1_MouseDown;

void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
    if (listView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y) is ListViewItem) {
      ContextMenu1.Show(Cursor.Position);
    } else {
      ContextMenu2.Show(Cursor.Position);
    }
  }
}
```

The MouseClick event fires only when a ListItem is clicked.

Comment: MouseUp would be a bit late for a contextmenue.

Comment: @TaW Not sure why you think so.  Most context menus appear on the mouse up.

Comment: You are right. Amazing - I could have **sworn** they come up with the MouseDown..

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on MouseClick.